# Visualforce controller to verify when batch job finishes and redirect to a list view

Tags: visualforce, batch, controller

Good afternoon, first of all thank you for your help.

I have a button on a Listview placed on a custom object that calls a visualforce page that starts a batch job, and what I want to do is to verify when this batch job is finished and then redirect the user to the same listview but only when the job is finished for the User to verify that all records were updated.

Right now my code is as follows:
VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="DailyDispatch__c" extensions="MassUpdateDailyDispatchController" recordSetVar="cases" lightningStylesheets="true" action="{!updateDispatchEndTime}" >
    <head>
        <apex:slds />
    </head>
    <body style="{!IF(isSelected,'','display:none;')}">
        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_brand slds-spinner_large">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>    

    <script>  
    if('{!isSelected}' == 'false'){
        alert('Please select atleast one record.');
        window.history.back();
    }else{
        if('{!msg}'.indexOf('Error') == -1){
            window.history.back();          
        }else{
            alert('{!msg}');
            window.history.back();                      
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Controller

```
public PageReference updateDispatchEndTime(){

    try{
        for(DailyDispatch__c d : selectedRecords){
            d.EndTime__c = System.now();
        }
        if(selectedRecords.size() > 0){
            Database.executeBatch(new DailyDispatchEndTimeBatch(selectedRecords), 2);    
            msg = 'Record(s) has been successfully updated.';
        }

    }catch(Exception e){ msg = 'Error!' + e.getMessage(); }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as an image. This can be hard for people with impaired vision to read, and also makes it impossible to copy-paste into our favorite IDE to try and read the code better.

Comment: Done @sfdcfox, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the job Id:

```
Id jobId;
public Boolean waitPoll { get; set; }

public void updateDispatchEndTime() {
  ...
  jobId = Database.executeBatch(...);
  waitPoll = true;
}
```

And then wait for the results:

```
public PageReference redirectWhenDone() {
  AsyncApexJob job = [select status from AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :jobId];
  if(job.Status == 'Aborted' || job.Status == 'Completed' || job.Status == 'Failed') {
    PageReference ref = ...;
    return ref;
  }
  return null; // Do not redirect, we are not done yet
}
```

...

```
<apex:actionPoller action="{!redirectWhenDone}" rendered="{!waitPoll}" interval="5" />
```